# Where is a service being started on Fedora 8?

Tags: linux

I can't figure out how MySQL and httpd (Apache) are being started on my Fedora 8 server.

The machine boots to runlevel 4 just fine. And somewhere along the way, MySQL and Apache are being started. But they are NOT being started via /etc/init.d -- checking chkconfig --list shows all "off".

And they're not mentioned in rc.local.

The ps ax output for httpd shows " /usr/sbin/httpd -f /home/webuser/helloworld/conf/httpd.conf" -- so it is being explicitly started with a specific config dir, etc.

Any ideas or further places to check for the startup would be most appreciated!

Thanks,

Larry
ps. The server is a Amazon pre-built server image based on Fedora 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start fishing with

```
find /etc -type f|xargs grep -i helloworld
```

That will do a recursive search on all the regular files in /etc for "helloworld" (case-insensitive)

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I'm new on this board, so I can't vote you up. So I'll give you 'right answer' even though the real right answer (for my specific situation) is below. Thanks again, Larry

Answer (score 2):

After much grepping, I found it: there were entries in root's crontab for event time "@reboot" --

```
# start mysqld on reboot
@reboot /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

To update: crontab -e  # (as root)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to {/etc/rc4.d/,/etc/init.d} and grepping for http and/or apachectl.  I have an app that distributes its own apache and mysql instances and it installs its own startup scripts as /etc/init.d/APPNAME-{WEB,DB}.